# Unable to call other activity as main activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I wanted to call login_activity (login credentials screen) as `main_activity` in Android studio.
I have written following code, but when I run the app, it is crashing.
I got to know that we should change the `main_acitivity` in `Android.Manifests.xml` file,corrected it, but app still crashing.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="My SRIB"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
```

Comment: Post crash error message. also, the manifest file is called `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: You should do a clean & rebuild

Comment: Please post your logcat :)

Comment: Logcat:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

Comment: Got the problem. I was calling findViewById before onCreate method,which I should not do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the problem. I was calling findViewById before onCreate method,which I should not do